# Problems about univariate and multivariate approach

Tags: statistics

Why is OMP called multivariate approach? Where in the algorithm reflect the "multivariate"?

The same can be asked for ANOVA: why is ANOVA called univariate approach? Where in the algorithm reflect the "univariate" ?

Comment: This question seems a better suit at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LuisMendo, thank you! I already repost there

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a statistic question rather than a programming question